# Random number in FOR loop expression in C language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, random, numbers

I'm trying to figure out the behavior of `for(i = 0; i < rand(); ++i)` where I'm not sure if the second expression is supposed to generate a new random number each time the loop iterate or just when it executes for the first time.

Tried to find out by comparing the program execution times but no luck as there were no big differences between them.

Does the random number generates once or each time the loop iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i=0` will be evaluated exactly once, before the loop begins.

`i < rand()` will be executed before each loop iteration - if the condition is ever false (IOW, if `i >= rand()`) then the loop will exit.  For each iteration of the loop `i` is compared to a different random number<sup>1</sup>.  If that's not what you want, then you need to save the result of `rand()` to a different variable and compare against that:

```
for ( int val = rand(), i = 0; i < val; ++i )
  // loop body
```

This will call `rand()` exactly once and save the result to `val`, and then `i` is compared to `val` each time through the loop.

`++i` is executed *after* each loop iteration.

---

1. Remember that `rand()` is a *pseudo*-random number generator - it uses a deterministic algorithm to generate a sequence of numbers, and the sequence it generates will be the same each time you run your program *unless* you use `srand` to seed it with a different starting value (typically by using the value returned from `time`).

Comment: That's exactly want. For i to be compared to a different random number each iteration. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`i < rand()` is evaluated each time round the loop, so `rand()` will be called each time round the loop.

The way to prove this to yourself would be to replace the call to `rand` with a call to a function that printed out some 'I have been called' information each time it is invoked.

Comment: What I really wanted was a way to know the number 'i' was compared to without calling the function out of the loop expression and storing it somewhere to compare it. Thank you!